# Known Java test suites with race condition hazard

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, race-condition

One feature of the tool I am developing is to detect potential race conditions within a Java unit test suite (hazards introduced not by the application but how the test suite is written.). Are there any known such suites for me to test on? BTW, it would be better that less native methods get involved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is to search few open source project issue trackers.

E.g.:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/AMQP-280?jql=text%20~%20%22test%20race%20condition%22

I bet some of them will be pretty complicated.